# Installing linux kernel 4.4.0-trunk-amd64 crashes X server

Tags: debian, xorg, linux-kernel

I have installed Debian 8 and xfce.
My machine is Lenovo Ideapad 500S. There's no information for this machine on how to properly use Debian on it.

When I install `linux-image-4.4.0-trunk-amd64` and reboot to start from that kernel, nothing appears.

Getting to the terminal and trying to do `startx` or restart the service `lightdm` doesn't work. X server gives up. lightdm status said something got failed.

500S has GeForce 940M. Nvidia homepage suggests installing 352.79 driver. It doesn't work. Even crashes X when booting on original 3.16.0.4 kernel. Also tried to install `nvidia-driver` package and let them handle it. No changes. still got black screen on 4.4.0 kernel booting.

What should I do?

Comment: Please add the detailed error messages Xorg and lightdm gave you.

Comment: Without appropriate information it's very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't still know how to use nvidia-driver on the kernel, but I at least succeed on successfully booting the computer with x server working.

After installing the kernel, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `nomodeset` in the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
```

Save the file, and do

```
sudo update-grub
```

Still it seems like there's a problem unsolved as I see something like `[  Failed  ]` on a boot log when booting up the computer. But it work at least. :(